# Define method return type according class received as parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to force the return type of the function according to a static attribute of a class received by the parameter?

In the code below, I expect the variable foo to be of type Date, equal to the `returnType` attribute of the class received as a parameter, but I don't know how it can be done, or if it is possible.

```js
function register<T extends { new(...n: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) {
           //       the error    \\ 
    return <constructor.returnType><unknown>new constructor(...args);
}

class Clazz {
    static returnType: Date
    constructor(p1: string, p2: number, p3: object) { }
}

let foo = register(Clazz, "", 1, {});
```

see the figure below to better illustrate:

[image: vscode type]

Another image to illustrate:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can create a type in order to request a class with `returnType` defined (static property):

```
type ClassWithReturnType = { new(...args: any[]): any; returnType: any; };
```

then you know you can extract the `returnType` with inference, like this:

```
type ClassReturnType<T extends ClassWithReturnType> = T['returnType'] extends infer R ? R : never;
```

At this point you just need to change the function declaration to:

```
function register<T extends ClassWithReturnType>(constructor: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>): ClassReturnType<T> {
    return (new constructor(...args));
}
```

However the thing that sounds strange to me is that you are calling `new constructor()` and expecting a `returnType` different from `T`. This is impossible, since constructor return an instance of the class T. Maybe you like to use this for other purposes / static methods, however I hope this answers your question.

Full code is:
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#)

```
type ClassWithReturnType = { new(...args: any[]): any; returnType: any; };
type ClassReturnType<T extends ClassWithReturnType> = T['returnType'] extends infer R ? R : never;

function register<T extends ClassWithReturnType>(constructor: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>): ClassReturnType<T> {
    return (new constructor(...args));
}

class Clazz {
    static returnType: Date;
    constructor(p1: string, p2: number, p3: object) { }
}

let foo = register(Clazz, "", 1, {});
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

responding about "whatahell am I doing with this", I am creating classes that return Proxy, to intercept some attributes, but I want to allow the user to continue working with the class as before.

Comment: Ahh, nice one, didn’t think about proxies!